# Uploading large files with Carrierwave to S3

Tags: file-upload, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, large-files

So I will need to upload large files (zip files that are a few GB large) to S3, and I would like Carrierwave to manage the download/distribution of those files.

Meaning, when a user pays Carrierwave can automagically generate the dynamic URL and send it to them. I know how to do this already, but it just occurred to me that I have never uploaded files via Carrierwave that are bigger than a few dozen MB, much less a few GB to S3.

Given the flakiness of HTTP connections, I figure this is a suboptimal way to do it.

I don't have that many files to upload (maybe 10 - 20 max), and users won't be uploading them. It will be a storefront where the customers will be buying/downloading the files, not uploading them.

It would be nice if there was a way for me to upload the files into my S3 bucket separately (say FTP, git, or some other mechanism) and then just link it to my app through Carrierwave in some way.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

Also, don't forget that you will encounter the Heroku 30 second timeout when you are uploading the file in the first place.

Don't worry though, there are options:

- Direct Upload - S3 supports direct upload where you present a form which uploads directly to s3 bypassing Heroku, you then receive a call back into your application with the uploaded files details for you to process (https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct)
- Upload to S3 and then expose bucket/folder in your application to connect to your models. We do this approach with a number of clients. They use Transmit (Mac Client) to upload large assets to S3 and then visit their app to link the asset to a Rails model.

Also, I'm pretty sure S3 is an HTTP based service so you're only going to be able to upload via HTTP.

Comment: I think I like your second option. i.e. using Transmit and then visiting the app to link the asset to a Rails model. How do I do that, on the app side? What would the code look like? Or can you point me to something in the Carrierwave docs that show me how to do that?